# What is better test design: Navigate directly to URL or navigate normally by clicking (as a real user would) in selenium tests

Tags: selenium, testing

Let us say my test wants to see if a user can see an image on XYZ page. And let's say in normal usage, the user can only go to XYZ page by clicking a link on ABC page (might be the home page).
Now assuming the URL to XYZ page is not static, but maybe depends on the image, and can be generated in the code simply, I have two ways of writing the test:

1. Generate the URL in test and directly navigate to XYZ, and then check if the image is present.
2. Go to ABC like a normal user would, click on the link which takes you to XYZ and then check for image

**For option 1**, I feel like I get more test isolation. If the link on ABC page is not generated correctly or is broken for some other reason, this particular test should not fail, right? That should be the responsibility of some other test?

**But for option 2**, that is how a real user would do it. He would almost never try to guess the pattern of the URL and then navigate to it directly. And I cannot have a huge test that goes to every link and sees if it is not broken, that would be way too complicated. So this much sacrifice in test isolation is needed.

How should I decide between the two options? Is there a right way? Hopefully the question is not too subjective for stackoverflow.

Comment: I've had requirements for both.  Option 1 as our pages where supposed to work when bookmarked and Option 2 as navigation was to be verified as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're wanting to test. If you want to test the buttons or links themselves (ie: you're testing the whole user workflow), click on them just like the user would.

If, on the other hand, clicking these links is just a means to an end and that the real target of the test case is deeper into the app, I think it's perfectly fine to skip directly to the part of the app you're actually testing.

Comment: So in this case I should have two tests with some overlap? One that directly goes and tests the XYZ page, and the other that tests the whole flow ABC->XYZ->image?

Comment: @AzureMinotaur: that's what I would do.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid overlap and follow DRY in a way across tests, but maybe that's not possible here?
As now if the image has some problem on page XYZ, both these tests will fail. One test subsumes the other. But thanks for your opinion, at least now I know doing it this way is not too bad.

Comment: @AzureMinotaur: it's not overlap when you're testing two different things. Test A: verify that clicking link "X" takes you to "Y". Test B: verify that on page B ... Those are two separate pieces of functionality to be tested.

Comment: Once you've tested clicking the link once, you don't need to test it again (in general). The rest of the tests can just navigate directly to the page.

Answer (score 0):

As an End User, best approach will be the Option 2 which also widen the coverage of your test hence you can check: 
1. Whether links/ buttons are clickable and not throwing exception.
2. Click on above is navigating to correct page.

Option 1, can be used for test scenario where user doesn't bother about how to reach to the page rather focused only on the opened page contents.
Choosing any of these option is depending on your approach of test coverage and its scope.

Comment: Thanks Ashish, makes sense :)